# Angular2 - Make component wait until the service is done fetching data, then render it

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, typescript

I'm having trouble implementing a service that loads the data (gyms array) once, then allows all other components to use it, without making other HTTP requests.

My application works fine if the user started at the title page and loaded all the data, but when I go to a specific detail page (.../gym/1) and reload the page, the object isn't in the service array yet. How can I make the component that tries to access the service array wait until the data is loaded? More specifically, how can I delay the call of gymService.getGym(1) in the GymComponent until the getAllGymsFromBackEnd() function is done populating the array?

I've read about resolvers but my tinkering led me nowhere.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code I was working on:

Service:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Gym} from "../objects/gym";
import {BaseService} from "./base.service";
import {Http, Response} from "@angular/http";
import {HttpConstants} from "../utility/http.constants";

@Injectable()
export class GymService extends BaseService {

   private gyms: Gym[] = [];

   constructor(protected http: Http, protected httpConstants: HttpConstants) {
      super(http, httpConstants);
      this.getAllGymsFromBackEnd();
   }

   getAllGymsFromBackEnd() {
      return super.get(this.httpConstants.gymsUrl).subscribe(
         (data: Response) => {
            for (let gymObject of data['gyms']) {
               this.gyms.push(<Gym>gymObject);
            }
         }
      );
   }

   getGyms() {
      return this.gyms;
   }

   getGym(id: number) {
      return this.gyms.find(
         gym => gym.id === id
      )
   }
}
```

Component:

```
import {Component, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {Subscription} from "rxjs";
import {Gym} from "../../objects/gym";
import {GymService} from "../../services/gym.service";
declare var $:any;

@Component({
   selector: 'app-gym',
   templateUrl: './gym.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./gym.component.css']
})
export class GymComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {

   private subscription: Subscription;
   private gym: Gym;

   constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
            private gymService: GymService
   ) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
      this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
         (param: any) => {
            this.gym = this.gymService.getGym(parseInt(param['id']));
         }
      );
   }

   ngAfterViewInit(): void {
      $( document ).ready(function() {
         $('.carousel').carousel();
      });
   }

   ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

Comment: Your service should expose an observable that things can *subscribe* to. For example, you can use a `ReplaySubject` to act as a cache. Make `getGyms` return `Observable<Gym[]>`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I made the changes as you suggested. Can you please take a  look and see if I did it right? I also have no idea how to implement the getGym(id) function and use it in the component, can you please help with that as well?

Comment: Don't change the question after it's attracted an answer. If you want to know if you've done it right, test it!

Comment: Yes, I tested the code in the description and it works (aside from getGym(id)), I'm just wondering if the implementation could have been simpler/better.

Comment: If you have working code that you think could be improved, once you've finished implementing everything, see [codereview.se].

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Resolver` as well. Check it here https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html or use Observable. So the `private gym: Gym;` will become `private gym$:Observable<Gym>;`, and in your template, use `async` pipe to get the data.